# removing a tag before adding it

Tags: d3.js

I'm trying to make sure that an element is removed before adding it.

Here is how I have it.

```
d3.select('.graph').remove();
d3.select('svg').append('line').attr('y',80).attr('x1',0).attr('x2',200).attr('class','graph');
```

So if I take out the 1st line, the line does draw.
However, if I add the 1st line, the line never gets drawn. It seems like even though the sequence should be remove and then add, but somehow, d3 is always drawing and removing.

What is missing in my code?

Comment: Can you post a bit more of your code? For example, does the svg element maybe also have a class "graph"?

Comment: Hey @nautat, no it doesn't. I'll edit on my post with the full code.

Comment: Actually, thanks @nautat for getting me to re-look. There is a loop going on that is removing the line. Yeah I concentrate too much on the d3 and not the logic since I'm new to it.

Comment: Did you figure this question out or were you planning on adding clarification? You could always delete the question if you've figured out the problem.